# How can one determine where remix exits?

Tags: remix

In something like this, how can I tell which `require` the contract exits on?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;


contract Demo {
    uint _a;
    function Demo(uint a) public {
        _a = a;
    }

    function demo() public view {
        require(_a == 1);
        require(_a == 2);
    }
}
```

All that's logged in the console is:

```
[call] from:0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c, to:Demo.demo(), data:01725...25a0b, return: 
Details
Debug
{}
 from   0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c
 to     Demo.demo() 0xcd021ffd464dc40614c4dd7e7826b3d91a21ab12
 transaction cost   21854 gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract)
 execution cost     582 gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract)
 input  01725a0b
 decoded input  {}
 decoded output     {}
 logs   []
call to Demo.demo errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information. 
creation of Demo pending...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, as suggested, debugging the transaction in Remix is the best available option. I don't find Remix's debugger to be that great, but it does allow you to step through the function. It won't let you step past the `require` that failed, so you can see where the `revert` happened.